# Errors while getting data in rpy query

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, rpy2

I need to get nasapower data with use rpy. In documentation r code works in this way:

```
library("nasapower")
daily_ag <- get_power(community = "ag",
                      lonlat = c(151.81, -27.48),
                      pars = c("RH2M", "T2M", "PRECTOTCORR"),
                      dates = "1985-01-01",
                      temporal_api = "daily"
                      )
```

I try to do this thing in rpy:

```
!pip3 install rpy2==3.5.1
import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr, data

utils = importr('utils')
base = importr('base')

utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)
utils.install_packages('nasapower')
nasapower = importr('nasapower')


nasapower.get_power("ag",
lonlat=[151.81, -27.48],
pars=["RH2M", "T2M", "PRECTOTCORR"],
dates="1985-01-01",                      
temporal_api = "daily"
                      )
```

and I got the error:

```
RRuntimeError: Error: You have entered an invalid value for `lonlat`. Valid values are `global` with `climatology` or a string of lon and lat values.
```

How should I solve my problem?

Comment: It really helps the community if you accept an answer if it solved your issue. So if somebody has this error in the future and they search it, they could see that it was solved. Doesn't have to be my answer at all... Whatever answer you feel that best solved your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need change `lonlat=[151.81, -27.48]` to `lonlat = robjects.vectors.FloatVector([151.81, -27.48])` based on the documentation.

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/vector.html#rpy2.robjects.vectors.FloatVector

Comment: nasapower.get_power("ag",lonlat = c(151.81, -27.48),pars=["RH2M", "T2M", "PRECTOTCORR"],dates="1985-01-01",
                          temporal_api = "daily"
                )

NameError: name 'c' is not defined

Comment: It is python code, not r. In r i works well

Comment: I am sorry for not understanding your question properly, please see the update answer.

Comment: RRuntimeError: Error: 1985-01-01 is not a valid entry for date. Enter as YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Being that this a different error, please ask a new question with the new title so people that know how to handle this error could help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the list to `FloatSexpVector`:

```py
!pip3 install rpy2==3.5.1
import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr, data
from rpy2.rinterface import FloatSexpVector # <<<

utils = importr('utils')
base = importr('base')

utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)
utils.install_packages('nasapower')
nasapower = importr('nasapower')


nasapower.get_power("ag",
    lonlat=FloatSexpVector([151.81, -27.48]), # <<<
    pars=["RH2M", "T2M", "PRECTOTCORR"],
    dates="1985-01-01",                      
    temporal_api = "daily"
)
```

Comment: RRuntimeError: Error: 1985-01-01 is not a valid entry for date. Enter as YYYY-MM-DD.